# Css card on hover border position

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I got an animation effect of setting the border of a card when it's hover over. But in case the card contents exceed, I had to make the card `overflow` set to auto to make the card scrollable. But in doing so, when hovered over the bottom of the card is taking the initial height of the card and displaying through the previous height only. I think I need to change something on the `.card:hover::before` but can't seem to figure it out. Have a look at the picture I've attached below for a better understanding. Check out my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xd1yr0je/

[image: Card when hovered over]

```
    .card {
      background-color: #222831;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: flex;
      height: 40%;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0 7px;
      width: 31%;
      opacity: 0.9;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #58cdd1;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.25s 0.0833333333s;
      transition: color 0.25s 0.0833333333s;
      position: relative;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .card::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .card::before,
    .card::after {
      border: 0 solid transparent;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      content: "";
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .card::before {
      border-bottom-width: 3px;
      border-left-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .card::after {
      border-top-width: 3px;
      border-right-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      color: #ffe593;
    }
    
    .card:hover::before,
    .card:hover::after {
      border-color: #eb196e;
      -webkit-transition: border-color 0s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s;
      transition: border-color 0s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .card:hover::before {
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.25s;
      transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.25s;
    }
    
    .card:hover::after {
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.25s, 0s;
      transition-delay: 0s, 0.25s, 0s;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the card has the default value of `box-sizing: content-box`, and you can fix this by changing that to `box-sizing: border-box` (it's a standard to do this on all elements in your CSS file) If you provide us the full code for this problem, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I would suggest adding the border on the actual card not on the ::before or :: after. If you hover you can change border properties. It will be a much easier solution.

Comment: @ThomasTromp added my js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xd1yr0je/

Comment: @SirExotic check out my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xd1yr0je/

Comment: @Brian tried doing that but then it's not showing the aniimated border at all..you may want to check my fiddle

Comment: Your issue the `width` and `height` of the `.card`  See if you remove width and height from `.card` the hover works 100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of solving this is to add a div inside the `.card`. Let's call it `.inner-card`. Add the `overflow-y:auto;` to the `.inner-card` and also remove the scrollbar in that div. That should fix your problem.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.card{
  height: 50%;
  width: 31%;
  background-color: #222831;
  border-radius: 5px;  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 7px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #58cdd1;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s 0.0833333333s;
  transition: color 0.25s 0.0833333333s;
  position: relative;
}

.card-inner {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.card::before,
.card::after {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.card::before {
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-left-width: 3px;
}

.card::after {
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-right-width: 3px;
}

.card:hover::before,
.card:hover::after {
  border-color: #eb196e;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s;
  transition: border-color 0s, width 0.25s, height 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card:hover::before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.25s;
}

.card:hover::after {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.25s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.25s, 0s;
}

.card:hover {
  color: #ffe593;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  opacity: 1;
}

.card h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-shadow: 5px 10px 7px #eb196e;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align:center;
}

.card__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card__container__details {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px 6px;
}

.card__tasks {
  width: 80%;
}

.task__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.main__task {
  display: flex;
  margin: 7px 0;
}

/* Checkbox Style */

.main__task label {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 550;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main__task input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.main__task i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #0b87a6;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.main__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ i {
  top: 1px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  height: 15px;
  width: 25px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.main__task span {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.main__task span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.main__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.main__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span {
  color: #eb196e;
}

.sub__task {
  display: flex;
}

.sub__task label {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 450;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub__task input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.sub__task i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #eb196e;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.sub__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ i {
  top: 1px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.sub__task span {
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.sub__task span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.sub__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.sub__task input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span {
  color: #0b87a6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-inner">
          <h2>Web Development</h2>
          <div class="card__container">
            <div class="card__container__details">
              Created By: Tridib Chatterjee on Oct 14, 2020, 2:18:59 AM
            </div>
            <div class="card__container__details">
              Modified By: Tridib Chatterjee on Oct 14, 2020, 2:18:59 AM
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card__tasks">
            <div class="task__list">
              <div class="main__task"><label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Angular</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>ngIf</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>ngFor</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Components</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Directives</span></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card__tasks">
            <div class="task__list">
              <div class="main__task"><label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Angular</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>ngIf</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>ngFor</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Components</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="sub__task">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name=""><i></i><span>Directives</span></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this works..but in doing so the h2 header takes `margin-left: 0` and I cannot make it center again anyway

Comment: Simply add text-align:center; to the h2. Edited my answer.